# with the condition that timeout for queue.get() has been set, still cannot read msg from queue normally

Tags: python, multiprocessing

first, I worked with `if not q.empty()`,

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, current_process
import datetime, time

def func1(q):
    for i in range(5):
        if not q.full():
            print('Put %s to queue...' % i)
            q.put(i)
        else:
            print(current_process().name, 'is Full', current_process())

def func2(q):
    while True:
        if not q.empty():
            i = q.get(block=True, timeout=1)
            print('Get %s from queue.' % i)
        else:
            print('queue empty')
            break

if __name__=='__main__':
    q = Queue(10)
    ProA = Process(target=func1, name='A', args=(q,))
    ProB = Process(target=func2, name='B', args=(q,))
    ProA.daemon = True
    ProB.daemon = True

    print(datetime.datetime.now(), ProA.name, 'is Alive:', ProA.is_alive())
    print(datetime.datetime.now(), ProB.name, 'is Alive:', ProB.is_alive())
    ProA.start()
    print('*' * 10, 'Since Now Start Subprocess A')
    print(datetime.datetime.now(), ProA.name, 'is Alive:', ProA.is_alive())
    print(datetime.datetime.now(), ProB.name, 'is Alive:', ProB.is_alive())

    ProA.join()
    print(datetime.datetime.now(), ProA.name, 'is Alive:', ProA.is_alive())
    print(datetime.datetime.now(), ProB.name, 'is Alive:', ProB.is_alive())

    ProB.start()
    print('*' * 10, 'Since Now Start Subprocess B')
    print(datetime.datetime.now(), ProA.name, 'is Alive:', ProA.is_alive())
    print(datetime.datetime.now(), ProB.name, 'is Alive:', ProB.is_alive())

    ProB.join()
    print(datetime.datetime.now(), ProA.name, 'is Alive:', ProA.is_alive())
    print(datetime.datetime.now(), ProB.name, 'is Alive:', ProB.is_alive())
```

and the result shows like this:

```
2022-01-01 16:34:07.211678 A is Alive: False
2022-01-01 16:34:07.211738 B is Alive: False
********** Since Now Start Subprocess A
2022-01-01 16:34:07.213302 A is Alive: True
2022-01-01 16:34:07.213384 B is Alive: False
Put 0 to queue...
Put 1 to queue...
Put 2 to queue...
Put 3 to queue...
Put 4 to queue...
2022-01-01 16:34:07.244838 A is Alive: False
2022-01-01 16:34:07.244857 B is Alive: False
********** Since Now Start Subprocess B
2022-01-01 16:34:07.245714 A is Alive: False
2022-01-01 16:34:07.245756 B is Alive: True
Get 0 from queue.
Get 1 from queue.
Get 2 from queue.
Get 3 from queue.
Get 4 from queue.
queue empty
2022-01-01 16:34:07.272992 A is Alive: False
2022-01-01 16:34:07.273008 B is Alive: False

Process finished with exit code 0
```

However, when I changed the condition to `if not q.qsize == 0`,
replace the part of `func2` with

```
def func2(q):
    while True:
        try:
            if q.qsize() != 0:
                i = q.get(block=True, timeout=1)
                print('Get %s from queue.' % i)
        except:
            print('q.qsize == 0')
            break
```

I got

```
2022-01-01 16:37:09.681813 A is Alive: False
2022-01-01 16:37:09.681980 B is Alive: False
********** Since Now Start Subprocess A
2022-01-01 16:37:09.684073 A is Alive: True
2022-01-01 16:37:09.684134 B is Alive: False
Put 0 to queue...
Put 1 to queue...
Put 2 to queue...
Put 3 to queue...
Put 4 to queue...
2022-01-01 16:37:09.720998 A is Alive: False
2022-01-01 16:37:09.721029 B is Alive: False
********** Since Now Start Subprocess B
2022-01-01 16:37:09.722099 A is Alive: False
2022-01-01 16:37:09.722140 B is Alive: True
q.qsize == 0
2022-01-01 16:37:09.761179 A is Alive: False
2022-01-01 16:37:09.761202 B is Alive: False

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I suppose here I should get a few values as output at least ...? however it seems that the code just jumped to the judge condition 'except', which means q.qsize here is equal to 0 ...???

Comment: Depending on the OS it's possible that prints of subprocesses do not show up. Check that with a simple `print()` line!

Comment: Your question is: why do you not get an error when calling `q.get` even though you check `q.qsize` is not zero before?

Comment: yes, you're right @IainShelvington I just revised my description ... and yes my question should be why I may get different result with the judge condition between ```q.qsize``` and ```q.empty()```

Comment: Did you read the docs on `multiprocessing.Queue` that states that methods `qsize`, `empty` and `full` are *not* reliable? You should not be writing code that uses these methods. Why don't you just state what it is you are actually trying to accomplish and I am sure there is a good solution that does not require any of these calls.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you are using queue methods that are documented as being unreliable so it's not clear how much effort should be expended trying to debug this.

Comment: @Booboo what I am trying to accomplish is to learn how to throw ```Queue``` into application via a simple example, as you saw in the description, and then I 'll be able to adopt it into a more complicated application in the future.

Comment: You don't just "throw" a `Queue` into an application; you have to have a clear purpose in mind. Right now you are making a series of unreliable queue calls and getting different results when you try different things.  Instead, state in plain English what you are trying to accomplish with `func1` and `func2`. For example, if you would like `func1` to put some number of items on the queue for `func2` to process and then they both terminate, you are going about it wrong. But you just cannot experiment with testing queue sizes and empty and full queue conditions.

Comment: @Booboo in my opinion, there should be no difference between using ```if not q.qsize ==0``` and ```if not q.emty()```, however the leading results shows actually they're quite different but I did not realize what was the reason. I suppose ```q.get(True)``` means once 1 element is taken out from the q and then qsize should minus 1... no?

Comment: Looking at the implementation code I see that the `multiprocessing.Queue.qsize()` and `multiprocessing.Queue.empty()` methods are implemented very differently and would not return consistent results. Taking one item from the queue *might* result in `qsize()` returning 1 less *if* the *producer* (the process putting the items) has already completed putting all the items it will ever be putting. At least that is what I have found to be the case empirically. But the documentation tells me not to rely on this, so I don't. I will have some code examples for you in a short while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some examples of how queues can be used. But first, there is something everyone needs to know about the underlying implementation. A `multiprocessing.Queue` is implemented using a [`multiprocessing.Pipe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=pipe#multiprocessing.Pipe), which has a limited capacity. That is, a process cannot send data to a Pipe's underlying connection in an unlimited fashion without ultimately blocking unless some other process is reading the data. Yet you can define a queue with an arbitrarily large capacity, even an infinite capacity, so that you can continue to issue `put` calls to the queue without ever blocking. How is that accomplished? The queue instance actually starts a new thread that is responsible for doing the underlying writing to the pipe and is is this thread that *will* block while the thread that called  `put` can continue to run. But what this means is that the process will not terminate until the thread that was created to write to the pipe terminates and it will not terminate until the pipe is able to accept the data. What does all this mean? If you have a process A that is a consumer of items on a queue put by producer process B, process A must first get all the items from the queue before attempting to `join` process B (i.e. wait for process B to complete) because process B may not be able to complete because it may be blocked waiting for process A to get items from the queue.

**Example 1**

In this example the main process starts two new processes, a producer of items, `func1`, and a consumer of those items, `func2`, and waits for both processes to complete. One of the simplest ways to handle this situation is for the producer to put a special *sentinel* item that cannot be confused for a regular item that indicates there are no more items left to process. In other words, the sentinel acts as an end-of-file indicator. So the consumer simply does blocking get calls on the queue until it detects the sentinel item and then it can terminate. In this case `None` is used as the sentinel.

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def func1(q):
    for i in range(10):
        print('Put %s to queue...' % i)
        q.put(i)
    # Put special item signaling there are no more:
    q.put(None)

def func2(q):
    while True:
        i = q.get(block=True)
        if i is None:
            # There will be no more items on the queue
            break
        print('Get %s from queue.' % i)

if __name__=='__main__':
    q = Queue()
    proA = Process(target=func1, name='A', args=(q,))
    proB = Process(target=func2, name='B', args=(q,))
    proA.start()
    proB.start()
    proA.join()
    proB.join()
```

**Example 2**

In this example, we have two queues: a "work queue", `work_q`, to which numbers to be squared are put and a "results queue", `results_q`, to which the results of squaring the items gotten from the work queue are put. As before `func1` puts a sentinel to the work queue to indicate there are no more items to process. `func2` does not need to put a sentinel to the results queue since `func1` knows how many results there should be on the queue.

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def func1(work_q, results_q):
    for i in range(10):
        work_q.put(i)
    # Put special item signaling there are no more:
    work_q.put(None)
    # There should be 10 results:
    for _ in range(10):
        print(results_q.get())

def func2(work_q, results_q):
    while True:
        i = work_q.get(block=True)
        if i is None:
            break
        results_q.put(i ** 2)

if __name__=='__main__':
    work_q = Queue()
    results_q = Queue()
    proA = Process(target=func1, name='A', args=(work_q, results_q))
    proB = Process(target=func2, name='B', args=(work_q, results_q))
    proA.start()
    proB.start()
    proA.join()
    proB.join()
```

**Example 3**

This example is similar to the previous example except `func1` does not bother writing a sentinel and so `func2` just loops forever getting from the work queue and putting to the results queue. Since `func2` never terminates, the process that targets this function must be a daemon process so that it terminates when the main process terminates.

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def func1(work_q, results_q):
    for i in range(10):
        work_q.put(i)
    # Put special item signaling there are no more:
    # There should be 10 results:
    for _ in range(10):
        print(results_q.get())

def func2(work_q, results_q):
    while True:
        i = work_q.get(block=True)
        results_q.put(i ** 2)

if __name__=='__main__':
    work_q = Queue()
    results_q = Queue()
    proA = Process(target=func1, name='A', args=(work_q, results_q))
    proB = Process(target=func2, name='B', args=(work_q, results_q), daemon=True)
    proA.start()
    proB.start()
    proA.join()
```

**Example 4**

In all the prior examples, the main process started producer and consumer processes and then did nothing but wait for the completion of these processes. It seems that we could have done with one fewer process, i.e. the main process itself could be the producer.

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue


def func(work_q, results_q):
    while True:
        i = work_q.get(block=True)
        if i is None:
            break
        results_q.put(i ** 2)

if __name__=='__main__':
    work_q = Queue()
    results_q = Queue()

    for i in range(10):
        work_q.put(i)
    # Put special item signaling there are no more:
    work_q.put(None)

    proc = Process(target=func, name='A', args=(work_q, results_q))
    proc.start()

    # There should be 10 results:
    for _ in range(10):
        print(results_q.get())

    proc.join()
```

Refer back to my opening discussion. **Note that here the main process is retrieving the 10 results from the producer *before* joining the producer.** If I were to move the statement `proc.join()` *before* the loop that calls `q.get()`, it would be a grievous error.

**Example 5**

Finally, there is an indirect way of "counting" queue messages without getting an explicit count and that is by using a [`multiprocessing.JoinableQueue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=joinablequeue#multiprocessing.JoinableQueue), which supports two additional methods `task_done()` and `join()`. In part, the documentation states:

**`task_done()`**: Indicate that a formerly enqueued task is complete. Used by queue consumers. For each `get()` used to fetch a task, a subsequent call to `task_done()` tells the queue that the processing on the task is complete.

**`join()`**: Block until all items in the queue have been gotten and processed.

The count of unfinished tasks goes up whenever an item is added to the queue. The count goes down whenever a consumer calls `task_done()` to indicate that the item was retrieved and all work on it is complete. When the count of unfinished tasks drops to zero, `join()` unblocks.

In the following example, the main process puts 10,000 numbers to be squared on the work queue. This time, however, the consumer process (which is also a producer of results), `func2`, puts an indeterminate number of results to the results queue. So the main process cannot simply use a counter to retrieve the results not knowing how many to count. Nor can `func2` put a sentinel item to the results queue because it is in an infinite loop and thus has no way of knowing where to insert the sentinel.

Therefore, we use a `JoinableQueue` for the work queue. The main process can then issue a call to `join` on the work queue and know that when that call completes that `func2` has processed all the items on the work queue, i.e. it has put all the results to the results queue. Therefore, the main process can do *non-blocking* gets in a loop until it gets a `queue.Empty` exception.

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, JoinableQueue
import queue


def func(work_q, results_q):
    # This function "returns" an indeterminate number of results:
    while True:
        i = work_q.get(block=True)
        # Just return results for even values of i:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            results_q.put(i ** 2)
        # Show we have processed the item from the work_q:
        work_q.task_done()

if __name__=='__main__':
    work_q = JoinableQueue()
    results_q = Queue()

    proc = Process(target=func, name='A', args=(work_q, results_q), daemon=True)
    proc.start()

    for i in range(10_000):
        work_q.put(i)

    work_q.join()
    # All items have been read from the work_q and whatever results there are
    # have been put to the results_q:
    cnt = 0
    try:
        while True:
            print(results_q.get(block=False))
            cnt += 1
    except queue.Empty:
        pass
    print(cnt, 'items retrieved')
```

Prints:

```
0
4
16
36
64
100
...
99760144
99800100
99840064
99880036
99920016
99960004
5000 items retrieved
```

**Example 6**

The above example, but this time just with "regular" queues and using sentinels for both the work and results queue. This also allows the main process to do something with the results as they are being produced rather than having to wait for all results to be written to the results queue, as was the case with the previous example.

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue


def func(work_q, results_q):
    # This function "returns" an indeterminate number of results:
    while True:
        i = work_q.get(block=True)
        if i is None:
            break
        # Just return results for even values of i:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            results_q.put(i ** 2)
    results_q.put(None) # all results have been put

if __name__=='__main__':
    work_q = Queue()
    results_q = Queue()

    proc = Process(target=func, name='A', args=(work_q, results_q))
    proc.start()

    for i in range(10_000):
        work_q.put(i)
    work_q.put(None) # All items have been put

    cnt = 0
    while True:
        result = results_q.get(block=True)
        if result is None:
            break
        print(result)
        cnt += 1
    print(cnt, 'items retrieved')

    proc.join()
```