# Having trouble using python multiprocessing queues to keep information from new processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am working on a project where I iterate through a list with hundreds of thousands of items and perform analysis on each one of them. As you can guess, this takes a lot of time; much more than I can reasonably allocate. So, I started researching multiprocessing to try to speed up the work, and I initially wrote a little test code to simulate my problem like this:

```
num_packages = []
for _ in range(10):
    num_packages.append(list(range(50000)))
result_nums = []

def task(index):
    nums = num_packages[index]
    for num in nums:
        print(num)
        for _ in range(10000):
            pass
        result_nums.append(num)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    processes = []
    for i in range(10):
        p = Process(target = task, args = (i,))
        processes.append(p)
    for p in processes:
        p.join()
    print(len(result_nums))
```

However, as is clear, the final print statement would print zero, and I soon realized that I could not rely on global variables in this manner to store the information from my many processes. Searching for a solution, I came across queues, and tried to implement them to fulfill the role of result_nums in my above code:

```
def task(nums, queue):
    for num in nums:
        for _ in range(10000):
            pass
        queue.put(num)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    num_packages = []
    for _ in range(10):
        num_packages.append(list(range(50000)))
    queue = Queue()
    processes = []
    for i in range(10):
        p = Process(target = task, args = (num_packages[i], queue))
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()
    res_list = []
    for p in processes:
        p.join()
    print(queue.qsize())
```

When I ran this code, though, the process did not stop, so I added some printlines and reran it only to find that not all numbers 1 ~ 50,000 were added to the queue, and at some point the numbers just stopped getting added and the process seemingly halted. I tried adding another process to remove items from the queue and append them to a list, but that didn't work either. What do I need to do to make queues (or something else, I guess) work in the manner I need? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why this happens, and a possible solution is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73078478/multiprocess-process-not-exiting-while-target-function-returns/73084802#73084802). Another better but more involved solution which uses sentinel items that you can use is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70556226/16310741)

Regardless, the way you are doing it now can be simplified by using pools:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def task(nums):
    results = []
    for num in nums:
        print(num)
        for _ in range(10000):
            pass
        results.append(num)
    return results


if __name__ == "__main__":
    processes = []
    num_packages = []
    for _ in range(10):
        num_packages.append(list(range(50000)))
    with Pool() as pool:
        results = pool.map(task, [num for num in num_packages])

    print(len(results))
```

Keep in mind that statements outside the `if __name__ ...` block will be run by new processes each time they are spawned. So creating variables there might not be a good idea if they are expensive to create (in terms of memory/cpu time). Instead, send a relevant chunk of the list to each process from inside the block, like in the above approach.

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate the response.